# Installed 16.10 now the whole thing is buggy.

Tags: updates, 16.10, reinstall

I just installed 16.10 today and it's made using my computer nearly impossible. I want to reinstall 16.04 and just get rid of 16.10 and never touch it again. I tried looking it up how to do it and the help page led me to [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) but I can't find the ubuntuinstaller. Can anyone else suggest something?

Comment: 16.04 is the stable LTS.  Unless you are a developer or have a specific system issue, you're usually fine sticking to the LTS versions.

Answer (score 2):

Create a LiveCD for 16.04 using either UnetBootin (which is cross-platform), and/or Rufus, which is Windows only. Be sure to utilize the correct image for your CPU architecture (64-bit=AMD64, 32-bit=i386, etc.).

After you have burned the disk image to either a CD or USB, boot the LiveCD by pressing F1, F8, F9, etc.-whichever button allows you to bring up your BIOS boot options.

Once you boot the LiveCD, I recommend you click "Try Ubuntu", access your internal hard drive, and transfer **any needed data** off of it.

After that, install GParted (be sure to not reboot, as a LiveCD will not retain your data), and wipe the internal disk. It is generally recommended to format it as Ext4.

After doing this, you can either reboot into the Live disk, or simply double click "Install Ubuntu" on the Live Disk desktop.

The *UbuntuInstaller* is, in essence, the "Install Ubuntu" part of a LiveCD.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I assumed that anyone who could get so far as installing 16.04 and upgrading it could figure out how to format a disk and reinstall. Guess not :/

Comment: I agree with you in general yet AskUbuntu is no forum or helpdesk and strives to provide answers that are helpful for future, potentially less experienced readers. +1 for the added detail.